# converting nested maps in clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, traversal

I have a nested map which looks something like this:

```
{"a" {:points 2} "b" {:points 7} "c" {:points 1} "d" {:points 3}}
```

And I would like to turn it into a sequence of a maps in order to sort (with **sort-by**) and print it afterwards.

```
({:name "a" :points 2}
 {:name "b" :points 7}
 {:name "c" :points 1}
 {:name "d" :points 3})
```

From the documentation I figured that I will need something like **postwalk** but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: I really liked mobytes answer. I provided an alternate for your pleasure ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(sort-by :name
         (map #(conj {:name (key %)}
                      (val %))
              {"a" {:points 2}
               "b" {:points 7}
               "c" {:points 1}
               "d" {:points 3}}))

-> ({:points 2, :name "a"}
    {:points 7, :name "b"}
    {:points 1, :name "c"}
    {:points 3, :name "d"})
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to print it in sorted order, why not simply put it into a sorted map? `(into (sorted-map) m)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like:

```
(sort-by :name 
  (for [[n m] my-map] 
    (into m {:name n})))
```

This makes use of a few handy techniques:

- Destructuring to break my-map into [key value] pairs
- The fact that you already have maps in the values, so you can use `into` to add to them
- A for comprehension to build the list
- `sort-by` to sort the final results